# Как вызвать перевод веб-страницы через Google Translate при нажатии кнопки или элемента списка?

Tags: jquery, javascript, google-translate, html, css

говорю сразу не предлагать просто додать на страницу гугл виджет, так как стилизация тега option невозможна,
перепробовал кучу плагинов JQuery, но при изменении стиля, меняються класы и айди елементов или даже происходит какой-то конфликт между скриптами и в результате стиль меняеться НО виджет не переводить страницу
также пробовал JQuery переводчики, но мне надо перевести страницу с польського на английський и наоборот, а этот переводчик переводит очень плохо

Answer (score 1):

Стилизация option невозможна?
Вот [либка](https://github.com/FlamesoFF/flamedJS/blob/master/libs/flamedJS.js). Там это возможно.